# Two different table join view

Tags: oracle, system-views

I'm trying to understand what he wants me to select because non of the tables or attributes have object_name or object_type. would anyone know what my teacher be talking about?

"Select object_name and object_type  to see what objects you own"

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read [ask], and post a [mcve].  Folks here are not mind readers.

Answer (score 1):

While connected to the standard `SCOTT` schema:

```
SQL> select object_name, object_type from user_objects;

OBJECT_NAME                    OBJECT_TYPE
------------------------------ ------------------------------
SALGRADE                       TABLE
PK_EMP                         INDEX
PK_DEPT                        INDEX
EMP                            TABLE
DEPT                           TABLE
BONUS                          TABLE

6 rows selected.
```

`USER_OBJECTS` is a system view that shows me what objects (tables, indexes, procedures, etc.) I own. Try it on your database, logged in as yourself.

Comment: @cZairKolmoslink - How about you use Google and search exactly for those two words?

Comment: I did the once I found didn't work. They gave me a error. 
SELECT V$TABLESPACE, COUNT(*)
FROM BASIC_DEPT_SNAP;
It told me "V$TABLESPACE" invalid identifier 
I found this from https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tspaces014.htm#ADMIN11410

Comment: never mind I hink I got it
COLUMN TABLESPACE_NAME FORMAT A18
COLUMN INITIAL_EXTENT FORMAT A18
COLUMN NEXT_EXTENT FORMAT A18
COLUMN  PCT_INCREASE FORMAT A18
set pagesize 50000
set linesize 200

SELECT table_name, 
INITIAL_EXTENT, 
NEXT_EXTENT, 
PCT_INCREASE
from all_tables;